# How to set a resolution 800x480 under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I have a 7" monitor Lilliput 669, and I am unable to set a native 800x480 resolution under Windows 7 - it is just not in the list.

I am using integrated Intel graphics, so I have no nVidia panel.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution - Intel driver configuration has the same options, as the nVidia driver, and allows to add custom resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop and select `Screen Resoloution` Then click on `Advanced Settings` (the blue link in the middle of the page`then go to monitor tab and uncheck`Hide modes not supported` or something like that!

Comment: It ain't there either, checked already.

Comment: Did you check on DVI or VGA output of your video card?!

Comment: Checked both of them

Comment: Found the solution - Intel driver configuration has the same options, as the nVidia driver, and allows to add custom resolutions.